# Give contributor accesss to a service principal id to my storage account

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

In data factory v2, I have created a linked service to O365 using a Tenant ID, Client ID and Access key.
But, O365 dataset only supports blob as sink with service principal authentication.
I have tried adding the client ID I had used for O365 connector a contributor role to my storage account. But, it is not found in the search. I am thinking client id is the service principal.
How can I add the same service principal I had used to create o365 connector in ADF to my storage account?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please try to search the service principal by its name but not search it by client id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client id is not supported in this case.

We need to search for a security principal by entering a string to search for name or email address.

So here you should search for the name of the service principal rather than client id.
[image]

Comment: I had an admin create this client id and key. I do not have access to AAD. Should I ask the same person for the service principal name also?
Thanks

Comment: @TejaRebb If you have access to the Azure AD blade on Azure portal, you can find the service principal name by searching for the client id under **Enterprise applications**. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG7vt.png)